How to insert into and search in a XML column?
From Claudio Biselli here I got inspiration to write this decrypting database script:
DECLARE @DBNAME SYSNAME;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DBNAME = DB_NAME(DB_ID());

IF (@DBNAME = 'MASTER')
BEGIN
    THROW 55000, 'MASTER database is selected, please run this against the encrypted database', 1;
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT DB_Name(database_id) AS [DB Name], encryption_state, * --encryption_state_desc
                    FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
                    WHERE database_id = DB_ID() 
                      AND encryption_state IN (5, 3))
BEGIN
    --THROW 55000, 'Selected database is not encrypted.', 1;
                 PRINT 'Selected database is not encrypted.'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'DECRYPTING..';
    --Skip if already in progress, instead jump to showing progress
    IF 5 <> (SELECT encryption_state 
             FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys 
             WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@DBNAME))
    BEGIN
        USE MASTER; 
        SET @SQL = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBNAME) + ' SET ENCRYPTION OFF;';
        exec sp_executeSQL @sql;
    END;
END;

Now I have a script that check what is currently running on my server and displays the query as XML:
DECLARE @str varchar(50)='DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY'

SELECT
    [Server Name] = @@servername,
    s.host_name,
    TheUser = s.original_login_name,
    r.session_id,
    r.command,
    [Percent Complete] = CONVERT(NUMERIC(6,2), r.percent_complete),
    [Start time] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), r.start_time, 113),
    [ETA Completion Time] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEADD(ms, r.estimated_completion_time, GETDATE()), 113),
    sdest.Query
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests r WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions s WITH(NOLOCK) ON r.session_id = s.session_id
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         COALESCE((SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(_)]
                   FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle)
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE), '') AS Query
     FROM 
         sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle)) sdest
WHERE
    query IS NOT NULL
    AND s.session_id <> @@spid

This is what I get:

The query column has Claudio's script above, in an xml format, that stats and finish with `<?  xxxx >'
here is the xml script as I have it:
<?_ DECLARE @DBNAME SYSNAME;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DBNAME = DB_NAME(DB_ID());

IF (@DBNAME = 'MASTER')
BEGIN
    THROW 55000, 'MASTER database is selected, please run this against the encrypted database', 1;
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DB_Name(database_id) As [DB Name], encryption_state, * --encryption_state_desc
    FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
    WHERE 
        database_id = DB_ID() AND encryption_state IN (5,3)
)
BEGIN
    --THROW 55000, 'Selected database is not encrypted.', 1;
                 PRINT 'Selected database is not encrypted.'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'DECRYPTING..';
    --Skip if already in progress, instead jump to showing progress
    IF 5 <> (SELECT encryption_state FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@DBNAME))
    BEGIN
        USE MASTER; 
        SET @SQL = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBNAME) + ' SET ENCRYPTION OFF;';
        exec sp_executeSQL @sql;
    END;
END;

?>

Now my 2 questions:

how can I save this into a xml variable or table, for example:

create table #radhe (x xml)

insert into #radhe values (MY_XML_ABOVE_HERE)


Me having declared and set this variable here
 declare @str varchar(50) = 'DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY'

How can I find in a XML column this @str?


Yes I want to check this:
select x 
from #radha
where `there is `DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY inside my x`


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Why do you need to use XML there at all? you have one row, also, your code doesn't fetch the statement correctly, you need to use offsets from dm_exec_requests to get the actual sql from multiple statement

Please try the following solution.
It is tricky to search inside XML processing instructions.
That's why it is possible, as in the Method #1, to retrieve its value as a calculated column of NVARCHAR(MAX) data type , and use LIKE clause to search inside of it.
Or, as in the Method #2, by using XQuery .value() and contains() methods directly.
SQL
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _query XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (_query) VALUES
(N'<?_ DECLARE @DBNAME SYSNAME;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DBNAME = DB_NAME(DB_ID());

IF (@DBNAME = ''MASTER'')
BEGIN
    THROW 55000, ''MASTER database is selected, please run this against the encrypted database'', 1;
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DB_Name(database_id) As [DB Name], encryption_state, * --encryption_state_desc
    FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
    WHERE 
        database_id = DB_ID() AND encryption_state IN (5,3)
)
BEGIN
    --THROW 55000, ''Selected database is not encrypted.'', 1;
                 PRINT ''Selected database is not encrypted.''
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT ''DECRYPTING..'';
    --Skip if already in progress, instead jump to showing progress
    IF 5 <> (SELECT encryption_state FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@DBNAME))
    BEGIN
        USE MASTER; 
        SET @SQL = ''ALTER DATABASE '' + QUOTENAME(@DBNAME) + '' SET ENCRYPTION OFF;'';
        exec sp_executeSQL @sql;
    END;
END;

?>'),
('<root/>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @search_str varchar(50) = 'FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys';

-- Method #1
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT _query.value('data(processing-instruction("_")[1])', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) t1(x)
WHERE x LIKE '%' + @search_str + '%';

-- Method #2
SELECT * 
, _query.value('contains(data(processing-instruction("_")[1]), sql:variable("@search_str"))', 'BIT') AS result
FROM @tbl
WHERE _query.value('contains(data(processing-instruction("_")[1]), sql:variable("@search_str"))', 'BIT') = 1;

